# Как установить Яндекс.Карты через Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager, yandex-maps-embed

Нужно интегрировать Яндекс.Карты на сайт, сделанный на Тильде. Карты импортированы через Конструктор карт, с разными точками продаж.

Лезу [в документацию](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/constructor/concepts/about-docpage/) — беру «**Пример 2.** Вставка интерактивной карты в определенный контейнер».

После настройки в GTM скрипт карт подгружается, но к контейнеру не привязывается.

Comment: есть пример где можно это увидеть?

Comment: Экспериментировал на [sibereco.tilda.ws](https://sibereco.tilda.ws). Код примерно тот же: [jsfiddle.net/0h8jxfaw](https://jsfiddle.net/0h8jxfaw/)

Comment: Я вижу здесь карту в пункте "Точки продаж". Где карта не появляется?

Comment: Должно быть как тут в футере: [sibereco.com](http://sibereco.com)

Comment: В футере сайта sibereco.com карта конструктора с кодом <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A1030851cd74a213f90dd7b9def818e4d2016c79328ca6e59bad5959d735b28a8&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=400&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
Тут sibereco.tilda.ws этого кода нет, поэтому и карты нет.

Comment: Так я же и говорю: скрипт подцепляется динамически, после загрузки GTM. Поглядите DOM.

Comment: Вы добавляете эту карту <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A1030851cd74a213f90dd7b9def818e4d2016c79328ca6e59bad5959d735b28a8&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=400&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true%22%3E%3C/script> ? Если да, то можете рассказать где она на странице?

Comment: Пришлось отказаться от GTM в пользу iframe:

`<iframe src="https://sibereco.com/iframes/map.html" frameborder="0" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>`

Но вопрос как подключить карты через GTM остается открытым...